# Possible bug on tagged questions ordered by votes

Tags: bug, status-norepro, sorting

I was reading the [android+notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android+notifications?sort=votes&pagesize=50) tags on SO (ordered by votes, 50 questions per page) and I've noticed that the last question on the first page has 0 votes; clicking on the second page though, questions start again from 6 votes and below.

Is this by design for some mysterious cause?

Comment: Possibly related: [Massively downvoted questions are still missing from the list of questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142458). This also wouldn't be the [first time this has happened](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95408/sorting-questions-by-votes-is-broken).

Comment: I can't see that - seems to have cleared out. Possible cache glitch that fixed itself.