# Sorting tagged questions by vote count

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, sorting, tags-page

There already appears to be handful of questions related to sorting by votes not working, but I haven't found any describing exactly the problem I am experiencing right now.

On Stackoverflow try to display e.g. [C# tagged questions sorted by votes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?sort=votes). What I see is shown in the below screenshot:
[image]

However, one can easily tell that there are far more C# tagged questions with thousands of votes than the only one which shows up in the results. Also, it is quite suspicious that there would be no questions having vote count between 2782 and 5.

Comment: Cache glitch, it happens from time to time and fix itself after a while, see [this comment by a dev](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167931/possible-bug-on-tagged-questions-ordered-by-votes#comment494648_167931).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We broke it! We meant well... this was part of some performance changes that really help the page-load time for most of the commonly hit pages, but: I introduced a subtle bug into the sorting code which meant that it wasn't so much "sort" as "corrupt".

I have deployed the fix, and hopefully normal service is now resumed.

See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309137

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, and based on [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167931/possible-bug-on-tagged-questions-ordered-by-votes#comment494648_167931) by a dev, it's a temporary glitch in some server side cache that usually resolves by itself after a while.

Until the team fix this for good, we can use the Search mechanism to reach the same goal: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bc%23%5d%20is%3aquestion

This will also show all C# questions, sorted by votes, without using the borked tag mechanism/cache.

Comment: Nah, actually a bug in this case. Marc is looking into it.